# Limit representation of the Gamma function

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence, gamma-function, integral-inequality

I was going through the proof for the limit representation of the Gamma function where to prove the interchange of the limit and integral is justified, the author uses the following two relationships to show $$\bf{0<e^{-t} - (1-\frac{t}{n})^n<\frac{t^2}{2n}, (0<t<n)}$$:

(i) $$\bf{1-e^{t}\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^n = \int_0^t e^{\tau}\left(1-\frac{\tau}{n}\right)^n\frac{\tau}{n}d\tau}$$

(ii) $$\bf{0 < \int_0^t e^{\tau}\left(1-\frac{\tau}{n}\right)^n\frac{\tau}{n}d\tau < \int_0^t e^{\tau}\frac{\tau}{n}d\tau = e^t\frac{t^2}{2n}}$$

Even though differentiating both sides of (i) is giving me LHS = RHS, I am not able to prove or understand where this relation is coming from. Also unable to prove the equality in (ii). Please help.

Comment: Or he wants to prove inequality using integrals? If so if $0 < \tau <t $ then $ O <\frac{ \tau}{n} < 1$ so clue is prove

Comment: @KamalSaleh I think it's the converse

Comment: No, I checked. It is not the converse.

Comment: Well, that's what you wrote...

Answer (score 0):

If so if $0 < \tau <t $ then $ O <\frac{ \tau}{n} < 1$ so clue is prove $0< x(1-x)<x$ wich after division by non zero x gives $1-x < 1$  wich is true for. $0< x< 1 $ becaulse such relations we have in integrals

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what relation you are referring to in the given problem

Comment: (i) is just Newton -Leibnith theorem. for integral.                                               (ii) is proven as I said or similarly

Comment: For (i) can you send a link or any reference material regarding Newton -Leibnith theorem and in (ii) I understood the inequality, I was having difficulty proving the equality in the end i.e. the value of the integral.